# StreamWriter is not working on Android (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a .txt file by pressing a button inside a Unity 3D game.
It works perfectly on PC but than nothing happens when I try the same with Android.

What am I missing?

```
public void Play(){
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("helloWorld.txt", true);
    tw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now);
    tw.Close();
}
```

PlayerSettings->OtherSettings->WriteAccess to External(SDCard) is already on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you are saving your data...

Maybe you need to use `Application.persistentDataPath + "MyFile.txt"`